# Strings no longer equal after encryption and decryption

Tags: php, character-encoding, encryption, mcrypt

I use the following class to encrypt and decrypt a string. After creating two identical strings, I encrypt one of the strings and then decrypt it. However, the decrypted string is no longer equal to its twin (even though they look identical in text form after the conversion) . Also, after taking the encrypt-decrypted string and its twin and convert them to hex use bin2hex, I find out that they look similar only that the string that got encrypted before has an addition number of zero at the end.

Can someone point out what I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

class proCrypt 
{

```
public function __set( $name, $value )
{
    switch( $name)
    {
        case 'key':
        case 'ivs':
        case 'iv':
        $this->$name = $value;
        break;

        default:
        throw new Exception( "$name cannot be set" );
    }
}

/**
*
* Gettor - This is called when an non existant variable is called
*
* @access    public
* @param    string    $name
*
*/
public function __get( $name )
{
    switch( $name )
    {
        case 'key':
        return 'abcd';

        case 'ivs':
        return mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB );

        case 'iv':
        return mcrypt_create_iv( $this->ivs );

        default:
        throw new Exception( "$name cannot be called" );
    }
}

/**
*
* Encrypt a string
*
* @access    public
* @param    string    $text
* @return    string    The encrypted string
*
*/
public function encrypt( $text )
{
    // add end of text delimiter
    $data = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv );
    return bin2hex($data);
}

/**
*
* Decrypt a string
*
* @access    public
* @param    string    $text
* @return    string    The decrypted string
*
*/
public function decrypt( $text )
{
    $text = pack("H*" , $text);
    return mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv );
}
```

} // end of class

Comment: Can you show us the var_dump() of each? (the unprocessed one and the one that has been encrypted and decrypted?)

Comment: Hi, thegreasyitalian I create two string: $text1 = 'money'; $text2 = 'money'; after encrypting and decrypting $text2 and convert both text to hex (bin2hex) I got the following output: text1: 6d6f6e6579 text2: 6d6f6e65790000000000000000000000

Comment: Use var_dump($text1) instead of echo for both strings, and see what that outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the bin2hex outputs. What about before bin2hex, just using var_dump()?

Comment: I got this: text1: string(5) "money" 
text2: string(16) "money"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a 16-length string padded with spaces, presumably. Try trim() before bin2hex() to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: It works great! I just use the trim(text2) and it comes out great. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Note, if the string to be dealt with has spaces and the beginning or end, the trim() function will delete them. So that's up to you to make sure your data doesn't need to keep those leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Encryption algorithms usually require input that is a multiple of some length (8 bytes, 16 bytes, etc) to work with their fixed "block size". Your input string may have gotten 0-padded to match. You could undo it by keeping track of the necessary padding based on your algorithm of choice (each algorithm will have its own block size and padding method), and undo it after the decryption.